# How does one Parallelize a shell script with arguments using GNU parallel?

Tags: bash, matlab, terminal, parallel-processing

I am new to bash scripting. I have a shell script that runs several functions for longitudinal image processing in Matlab through terminal. I would like to parallelize the process in the terminal.

Here is a brief example of how it runs:

```
./script.sh *.nii -surface -m /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin/matlab
```

`*.nii` refers to images from a single subject taken at different times (i.e. subj1img1 subj1img2 subj3img3). There are 3 images per subject in my case. So in each run, the script runs through all images of a single subject.

I would like to parallelize this process so that I can run this script for multiple subjects at the same time. Reading through GNU parallel with my little experience I wasn't able to figure out the code I need to write to make it happen. I'd really appreciate if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Update your question to meet the standard of [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [Mechanical Turk detection actived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk). SO is not a "we do your coding" for you site. So please show effort on what you tried to code and what failed. End of Triage Review. .. and finish the tour ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
parallel ./script.sh {} -surface -m /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin/matlab ::: *.nii
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. so I tried this and given that I want to have a pair of files in each iteration I used two {} {}. But it seems like despite me defining the max number of jobs for parallel as 3, it opens MATLAB not 3 times but as many times as the number of file pairs (10 in this case). Not sure what to do with that because it will overload my system. Is there anyway to tell parallel to exactly have 3 jobs at any time? This is my code: parallel --jobs 3 ./cat_batch_long.sh  {} {} -surface -m /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin/matlab ::: *.nii

Answer (score 0):

you can start them in the background using & in a for loop as below :

```
for f in *.nii
do
  ./script.sh "$f" -surface -m /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin/matlab &
done
```